Why do migrations run faster under `./manage.py test` compared with `./manage.py migrate`?
edit: It's looking like Sentry was the culprit!!!!!! I ran cprofile to find out.
Why do migrations run faster under ./manage.py test compared with ./manage.py migrate (on a fresh database)? I'm not running an in memory database for unit tests or anything like that. Both the proper app and the unit test db use the same mysql docker container. I am using the NoseTestRunner.
This came up because I am trying use the Pytest runner but I found that it was much slower.
I know that ./manage.py test is in fact running the migrations, there are no shortcuts like that.
I have verified that the same number of migrations are being applied in the ./manage.py test case as the Pytest case.
I'm guessing some database optimization is being applied, like removing constraints or something.
I have these two dependencies installed.
django-nose==1.4.7
Django==3.2.25

Usually the migrations on "test" run on an empty database that is used just for the tests. Do you have data in your Main database? That could slow down the migrations depending on the actions the migration takes.

Good comment, I wasn't clear (updated the original post), in my testing here I ran the migrations on a fresh database. This is really about discovering why Pytest is so much slower, and Pytest would be on a fresh database. In my specific context it's 1.5min vs 10min.

I haven't used django-nose recently, but just had a look at the package.
The README says It also provides: Reuse of previously created test DBs, cutting 10 seconds off startup time Maybe it is just using an existing DB and not running the migrations every time.
